# How to use Jest to test functions using crypto or window.msCrypto

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, window.crypto

When running unit tests with Jest in react the `window.crypto` API is causing problems. I haven't found a way to incorporate `crypto` in Jest without installing other packages which is something I can't do. So without using another npm package is there a way to test functions that use: `crypto.getRandomValues()` in them that doesn't crash Jest? Any links, advice, or tips are appreciated

Comment: If you update jest to v29 (https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29#jsdom-upgrade) that issue is resolved. We don't need to mock crypto anymore

Comment: I simply changed `testEnvironment` to `"node"` instead of `"jsdom"` in `jest.config.ts` and it fixed the problem. Looks like `jsdom` lacks so much. `jsdom` also lacks `blob.arrayBuffer()` function.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use the following code to set up the `crypto` property globally. It will allow Jest to access

- `window.crypto` in the browser environment
- `global.crypto` in non-browsers environments. (Node/Typescript scripts).

It uses the [`globalThis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) which is now available on most of the latest browsers as well as Node.js 12+

```
const crypto = require('crypto');

Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'crypto', {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: arr => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length)
  }
});
```

Comment: This seems so straightfoward but isn't working for me; my test continues to fail with the same crypto.getRandomValues()-not-supported message. Any common gotchas for this?

Comment: @RwwL try `global.crypto = crypto`

Comment: How about subtle of Crypto? You could give an example that expands on your answer like when you need to generate a crypto key pair or so

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck in the same issue with crypto.subtle.digest, can someone please help?

Comment: `getRandomValues` doesn't return the values, it fills a typed array with values.  Use mitchelc's answer.

Comment: This has recently begun failing for me with the error "Value of "this" must be of type Crypto"

Comment: If you update jest to v29 (https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29#jsdom-upgrade) that issue is resolved. We don't need to mock crypto anymore

Comment: Better to do this in setupTests.js than your test file.

Answer (score 40):

Like @RwwL, the accepted answer did not work for me. I found that the polyfill used in this library did work: [commit with polyfill](https://github.com/whawker/react-jsx-highcharts/commit/03f6de060d0190e03e4181dad0c8a1f51585a710#diff-f70492f875b7aba999cd436bd6bf4eeb)

```
//setupTests.tsx
const nodeCrypto = require('crypto');
window.crypto = {
  getRandomValues: function (buffer) {
    return nodeCrypto.randomFillSync(buffer);
  }
};
```

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
 //...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.tsx"],
};
```

Comment: You saved my life by adding that to the setupTest files cheer my man

Comment: @mitchelc I got this error after configuring this "    TypeError: crypto.getRandomValues is not a function".

Comment: I used a similar approach in a test setup function: `if (!("crypto" in globalThis)) globalThis.crypto = require("crypto");`

Answer (score 24):

Since node 15.x you can use `crypto.webcrypto`

eg.

```js
import crypto from "crypto";

Object.defineProperty(global.self, "crypto", {
  value: {
    subtle: crypto.webcrypto.subtle,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 22):

For nodeJS + typescript, just use `global` instead of `global.self`

```js
import crypto from 'crypto'

Object.defineProperty(global, 'crypto', {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: (arr:any) => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length)
  }
});
```

Comment: After updating to Create React App v5.0.0, `global.self` stopped working for me (it did before). Removing `.self` fixed it.

Comment: The other answers did not work for me. This answer works with nodeJs 18, create-react-app (react-scripts 5.0.1) with typescript (4.9.5). I used it for randomUII() instead of getRandomValues() by replacing getRandomValues with `randomUUID: () => crypto.randomUUID()`. Just add this answer to setupTests.ts

Answer (score 9):

The polyfills in the current answers are incomplete, since `Crypto.getRandomValues()` modifies its argument in-place as well as returning it. You can verify this by running something like `const foo = new Int8Array(8); console.log(foo === crypto.getRandomValues(foo))` in your browser console, which will print `true`.

`getRandomValues()` also does not accept an `Array` as its argument, it only accepts integer [`TypedArray`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray). Node.js' `crypto.randomBytes()` function is not appropriate for this polyfill, as it outputs raw *bytes*, whereas `getRandomValues()` can accept signed integer arrays with elements up to 32 bits. If you try `crypto.getRandomValues(new Int32Array(8))` in your browser, you might see something like `[ 304988465, -2059294531, 229644318, 2114525000, -1735257198, -1757724709, -52939542, 486981698 ]`. But if you try `node -e 'console.log([...require("crypto").randomBytes(8)])'` on the command line, you might see `[ 155, 124, 189,  86, 25, 44, 167, 159 ]`. Clearly these are not equivalent, and your component under test might not behave as expected if tested with the latter.

The latest versions of Node.js solve this problem with the [`webcrypto` module](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html) (should be a matter of setting `globalThis.crypto = require('crypto').webcrypto`). If you're using an older version of Node (v14 or below) you might have better luck using [`crypto.randomFillSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randomfillsync_buffer_offset_size), which should be useable as a drop-in replacement for `getRandomValues()` as it modifies a passed buffer/`TypedArray` in-place.

In your Jest setup file (can't be set via the [`globals` configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globals-object) as it only allows JSON-compatible values):

```
const { randomFillSync } = require('crypto')

Object.defineProperty(globalThis, 'crypto', {
  value: { getRandomValues: randomFillSync },
})
```

Answer (score 9):

For the ones using `jsdom` (`jest-environment-jsdom`) environment with `Jest >=28` you should define replacement module as a **getter**.

```js
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  rootDir: './',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/test/setup-env.tsx"],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
};
```

```js
// setup-env.tsx
const { Crypto } = require("@peculiar/webcrypto");
const cryptoModule = new Crypto();

Object.defineProperty(window, 'crypto', {
  get(){
    return cryptoModule
  }
})
```

I am using `@peculiar/webcrypto` but other implementations should work also.

Comment: this is so far in my opinion the best approach,  others messing with the globalThis will work but the question is about the window object. 

If you don't need "@peculiar/webcrypto" you can simply do the below


`Object.defineProperty(window, 'crypto', {
  get() {
    return require('crypto');
  },
});`

Answer (score 7):

I'm using vue-jest, and what worked for me is the following configuration in `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   setupFiles: [
      '<rootDir>/tests/settings/jest.crypto-setup.js',
   ],
};
```

and in `jest.crypto-setup.js`:

```
global.crypto = { 
     getRandomValues: (arr) => require('crypto').randomBytes(arr.length) 
};
```

Adding the `getRandomValues` function definition directly in `module.exports` didn't work since the `globals` object must be json-serializable (as it is specified here: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globals-object).

Comment: I tried many solutions (using React + TS) and this is the one that worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Just want to chime in and say that this worked for me as well. I use CreateReactApp which expects the file src/setupTests.js to contain these types of definitions. I added the setupTests.js file and used the exact code specified in marinona21's jest.cypto-setup.js file.

Comment: `globalSetup` option doesn't work for me. This one does. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Deriving from AIVeligs answer:

Since I use "node" environment in Jest I had to use

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "ts-jest",
  testEnvironment: "node",
  globals: {
    crypto: {
      getRandomValues: (arr) => require("crypto").randomBytes(arr.length),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

The default `crypto` dependency didn't work for me during testing with Jest.

Instead I used the `@peculiar/webcrypto` library:

```
yarn add -D @peculiar/webcrypto
```

Then in your Jest setup file, just add this:

```js
import { Crypto } from "@peculiar/webcrypto";


window.crypto = new Crypto();
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me, I get an error about `window.crypto` being readonly.

Answer (score 4):

**dspacejs's** answer almost worked for me, except I had the same problem as **Mozgor**. I got an error saying that window.crypto is readonly. You can use Object.assign instead of directly trying to overwrite it.

Install @peculiar/webcrypto with `yarn add -D @peculiar/webcrypto` or  `npm i --save-dev @peculiar/webcrypto`

Then add the following to your Jest setup file:

```
import { Crypto } from "@peculiar/webcrypto";

Object.assign(window, {
  crypto: new Crypto(),
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `crypto` global for your jest environment as if it were in browser.
Your jest.config.js should look like:

```js
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
  globals: {
    ...defaults.globals,
    crypto: require('crypto')
  }
};
```

Ref: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem in Angular 8 with Jest tests for lib that are using uuid generator. In jest test setup i mock this:

```
Object.defineProperty(global.self, 'crypto', {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: arr => arr
  },
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Building upon what others suggested here, I resolved the issue with window.crypto.subtle.digest with the following:

```
Object.defineProperty(global.self, "crypto", {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: (arr: any) => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length),
    subtle: {
      digest: (algorithm: string, data: Uint8Array) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          resolve(
            createHash(algorithm.toLowerCase().replace("-", ""))
              .update(data)
              .digest()
          )
        );
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Or, if not using Typescript:

```
Object.defineProperty(global.self, "crypto", {
  value: {
    getRandomValues: (arr) => crypto.randomBytes(arr.length),
    subtle: {
      digest: (algorithm, data) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
          resolve(
            createHash(algorithm.toLowerCase().replace("-", ""))
              .update(data)
              .digest()
          )
        );
      },
    },
  },
});
```

The reformating of the string is optional. It is also possible to hardcode the algorithm, e.g. by stating 'sha256' or 'sha512' or alike.

Comment: Thanks! This work for me for `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'digest')` error

Comment: Worked well thx a lot.
I just had to parse that this is missing 
import { createHash } from 'crypto';

Answer (score 2):

late to the party, but I usually do something like:

```js
// module imports here
// important: the following mock should be placed in the global scope

jest.mock('crypto', function () {
  return {
    randomBytes: jest
      .fn()
      .mockImplementation(
        () =>
          'bla bla bla'
      ),
  }
});

describe('My API endpoint', () => {
  it('should work', async () => {
    const spy = jest.spyOn(DB.prototype, 'method_name_here');
    // prepare app and call endpoint here
    expect(spy).toBeCalledWith({ password: 'bla bla bla' });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
global.crypto = crypto;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the default configuration, [Jest assumes you are testing a Node.js environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string). But when you are getting errors using methods of the `window` object, you are probably making a web app.

So if you are making a web app, you should use "jsdom" as your "testEnvironment". **To do this, insert `"testEnvironment": "jsdom",` into your Jest configurations.**

If you maintain a "jest.config.js" file, then add it like:

```
module.exports = {
   ...
   "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
   ...
};
```

Or if, like me, you keep the Jest configs in "package.json":

```
{
    ...,
    "jest": {
        ...,
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to resolve the issue, just changes the environment...?

Answer (score 1):

**Depency injection** is one way to solve this.

Node.js provides an implementation of the standard Web Crypto API. Use require('node:crypto').webcrypto to access this module.

So you pass the crypto object to the code that depends on it.

Notice how we "inject" the correct crypto object when invoking the method `utils.aesGcmEncrypt`

```
test("Encrypt and decrypt text using password", async () => {
  const password = "Elvis is alive";
  const secret =
    "surprise action festival assume omit copper title fit tower will chalk bird";
  const crypto = require("crypto").webcrypto;
  const encrypted = await utils.aesGcmEncrypt(crypto, secret, password);
  const decrypted = await utils.aesGcmDecrypt(crypto, encrypted, password);

  expect(decrypted).toBe(secret);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented it using jest and it failed to execute after I upgraded jest version. Earlier I was using in this way :

```
global.crypto = {
 getRandomValues: jest.fn();
}
```

After upgrade, it was failing. So I tried in this way :

```
global.crypto.getRandomValues = jest.fn();
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: This one helped me a lot: global.crypto.randomUUID = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'bla bla bla')

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the `randomUUID` function from the `crypto` module in a Node.js environment where it might not be available (e.g., older Node.js versions), you can mock it using Jest. This can be particularly useful in testing scenarios. To achieve this, you can utilize a utility library like [FakerJS](https://fakerjs.dev/) to generate UUIDs.

Here's how you can set up the mock with Jest:

First, create a Jest setup file to include your mock:

```
// jest.setup.js

import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';

// Mock `crypto.randomUUID` which may not be available in some NodeJS environments
crypto.randomUUID = () => faker.string.uuid();
```

Then, make sure to reference this setup file in your Jest configuration:

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/path/to/jest.setup.js'], // Correct key to include setup file
  // Include the rest of your Jest configuration here
}
```

Note the correction in the FakerJS method to generate UUIDs (`faker.datatype.uuid()` instead of `faker.string.uuid()`), and the use of `setupFilesAfterEnv` instead of `setupFiles` in the Jest configuration to ensure the mock is applied correctly after all Jest environments have been set up.

This setup will allow you to use `crypto.randomUUID()` in your Jest tests as if it were natively supported in your Node.js environment, leveraging FakerJS to generate the UUIDs.