# crypto.getRandomValues() not supported in React.js

Tags: reactjs, uuid, react-testing-library, avalara

There is a npm package we made for our team usage and inside that we are using this `uuidjs`. Now I have installed this custom npm package on my Create-React-App which am testing with `testing-library`.

When I test the component which imports the files from this custom package which has `uuidjs` I get following error:

```
crypto.getRandomValues() not supported. See https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid#getrandomvalues-not-supported
```

I know there are answers to this questions is `install react-native-get-random-values`. But my confusion is can I install this in CRA which uses React.js? Is `react-native` has anything to do with it or its independent?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Jest to test functions using crypto or window.msCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612122/how-to-use-jest-to-test-functions-using-crypto-or-window-mscrypto)

Comment: If you update jest to v29 (https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29#jsdom-upgrade) that issue is resolved. We don't need to mock crypto anymore

Answer (score 4):

## Problem

When you run your test, I suspect you are running it in a test environment running in Node.js. [`crypto.getRandomValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) is only available from web APIs. It does not exist in Node under `crypto`, see Node's [documentation on `crypto`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html). Node does provide a [web crypto API](https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#webcrypto_web_crypto_api) which has `getRandomValues` but the `uuid` library won't be aware of it.

## Solution

You could mock or polyfill `crypto.getRandomValues` yourself, see: [How to use Jest to test functions using crypto or window.msCrypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612122/how-to-use-jest-to-test-functions-using-crypto-or-window-mscrypto).

Comment: If you update jest to v29 (https://jestjs.io/docs/upgrading-to-jest29#jsdom-upgrade) that issue is resolved. We don't need to mock crypto anymore

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue and able to resolve with polyfills.

Added following configs to **jest.config.ts**

```
...
setupFiles: ['./jest.polyfills.ts'],
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setup-tests.ts'],
...
```

Added **jest.polyfills.ts** file to project root.

```
if (typeof global.crypto !== 'object') {
    global.crypto = crypto;
}

if (typeof global.crypto.getRandomValues !== 'function') {
    global.crypto.getRandomValues = getRandomValues;
}

function getRandomValues(array) {
    return crypto.webcrypto.getRandomValues(array);
}
```